# We can create instance attrbitues for objects in Python. Can we create instance methods (not class Methods) as well in Python?

Tags: python, oop, instance-variables

How To create a methods which are common to a particular object just like creating instance attrbitue **obj.instance_attribute**
A method which belongs specifically for a single object ?

The link contains the code. I need to create method only for this object and not all instance of class.
[Creating class methods and attribute. The instance attrbitue. How to create instance methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvJvg.png)

> > > class A():
> > > def **init**(self):
> > > self.class_variable = 999999
> > > def class_methods(self):
> > > #available to all object
> > > print("Hey")

> > > obj = A()
> > > obj.class_variable
> > > 999999
> > > obj.class_methods()
> > > Hey
> > > obj.instance_attribute = 40404040 #common to particular object
> > > obj.instance_attribute
> > > 40404040
> > > #a method which is common to only this object
> > > obj.new_method():

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

> > > obj.new_mehtod(self):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

> > > 

Comment: please format your code properly and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as code. Read the [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more infos on how to ask good questions

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up terminology. Every "normal" method is a instance method - that means it applies the function without affecting any other instances of this class. To reference the instance, use the passed `self` keyword.

Defining a method for a single instance inside the generator/ class definition does not make sense in an OOP-context. If you create a car class, every instance of this class should be able to access its methods, like `drive()`.
The only way to add a unique function is to add it after instantiating the object. This can be done with the types.MethodType method, which binds the function to the class instance:

```
from types import MethodType
def fly(self):
    print(f"i, {self.name}, can fly")


class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


car_1 = Car("car one")
car_2 = Car("car two")
car_1.fly = MethodType(fly, car_1)
car_1.fly() # i, car one, can fly
car_2.fly() # AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'fly'
```

As you can see, car_1 has the class `fly`, which references car_1's name, while car_2 does not have this function.

But you should seriously reconsider what you are trying to achieve here.